# How do I add dates to my sidekiq.log log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, logging, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I'm using Rails 5.0 with sidekiq on Ubuntu Linux.  I start sidekick like so

```
cd $APP_ROOT && bundle exec sidekiq -d -P $SIDEKIQ_PID -L $APP_ROOT/log/sidekiq.log -c 1 -e $ENV
```

and have this in my config/initializers/sidekiq.rb file

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR']}:#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT']}/12" }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR']}:#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT']}/12" }
end

Sidekiq.redis { |conn| conn.flushdb }
```

I notice though in my log/sideiiq.log file, my "puts" output statements from my Rails code appear as is, and I would like a date to appear in front of them.  How can I change my configuration so that a date appears in front of each output line in my sidekiq log file?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options inside a Sidekiq worker:

```
def perform(args)
  logger.info "My message"
  Sidekiq.logger.info "Another"
  Rails.logger.info "Third!"
end
```

Comment: My sidekiq worker is invoking other services and those services are using "puts".  How would I add dates given that scenario?  Or are you sayihng I have to change all my puts' into "logger.info"s or whatever?

Comment: Yes.  Use the logger provided by the framework.  Production code should never use `puts`.